# VBA - Copy multiple selected files from 1 folder to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to select multiple .jpg file in a folder and copy it to another folder. This is the code I am working with, but it doesn't seem to be able to move it to the destination file.

I'm also using an excel worksheet where I paste those filenames which I want to copy in Row A.

```
Sub CopyFiles()

    Dim xDir As String
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim FNames As String

    FromPath = "Directory"  'Folder From
    ToPath = "Directory"   'Folder To

    Worksheets("Files to Copy").Activate

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show = -1 Then
            xDir = .SelectedItems(1)
            xFile = Dir(xDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
            Do Until xFile = ""
                xRow = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)
                If xRow > 0 Then
                    Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
                    ToPath & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
                End If
                xFile = Dir
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyFiles()

    '// Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FromPath$, ToPath$
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim xFolder As Folder

    FromPath = "Directory"  'Folder From
    ToPath = "Directory"   'Folder To

    Worksheets("Files to Copy").Activate

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If Not .Show Then Exit Sub
        Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
        For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
            On Error Resume Next
            xRow = Application.Match(xFile.Name, Range("A:A"), 0)
            If Err = 0 Then
                xFile.Copy ToPath & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!

I've activated the runtime and added in the directories in the code.
However when I run it, there is a Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Did you set the reference as I pointed in comment? `Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Comment: Yup, micosoft Scripting Runtime was ticked. I clicked debugged and it highlighted the "Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))"

Comment: Oops! Missed `Set fso = New FileSystemObject`! Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...copy or Move one file

For one file you can use the VBA Name and FileCopy function and for entire folders or a lot of files use the other macro example's on this page.

Copy or Move one file

For one file you can use the VBA Name and FileCopy function and for entire folders or a lot of files use the other macro example's on this page.

```
Sub Copy_One_File()
    FileCopy "C:\Users\Ron\SourceFolder\Test.xls", "C:\Users\Ron\DestFolder\Test.xls"
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub Move_Rename_One_File()
'You can change the path and file name
    Name "C:\Users\Ron\SourceFolder\Test.xls" As "C:\Users\Ron\DestFolder\TestNew.xls"
End Sub
```